# React starter kit and GraphQL arguments

Tags: reactjs, graphql-js, react-starter-kit

Im trying out react starter kit and have some confusion with GraphQL and parameters. I just don't know how to pass parameters to the query:

```
fetch('/graphql', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                query: '{searchquery{title}}',
            })
        });
```

It's searchquery that should have a string argument somehow.

Comment: Since you're using React and GraphQL, you may want to give [Relay](https://github.com/facebook/relay) a shot. Relay automatically manages necessary queries and caching of the results. You just need to declare the data requirements, without having to worry about how to construct the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question.

```
fetch('/graphql', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            query: '{searchquery(query:"test"){title}}',
        })
    });
```